# jQuery close/toggle div by clicking body

Tags: jquery, loops, click

In this small jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PcWjA/22/ I am trying to make a ul go display:none when there's a click on the body (or anywhere *not* on the list items) and that workst the first time there's a click on the body. But after that the script seems to loop and shows/hides the ul to flash.

Comment: I don't want to sound like a jerk, but the answer you accepted is a little overcomplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another answer
[http://jsfiddle.net/FfBzT/](http://jsfiddle.net/PcWjA/22/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hour_dropdown').hide()
    $(window).click(function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).hasClass("hour_dropdown") ||
            $(event.target).parents(".hour_dropdown").size() > 0 ||  
            $(event.target).hasClass("more")){
                 // do nothing....
            } else {
                    $('.hour_dropdown').fadeOut(200);
            }
    });
    jQuery('.more').click(function() {
        //if ($('.hour_dropdown').css("display")=="none") {
            $('.hour_dropdown').fadeToggle(200);
        //}
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, so your solution is using size bigger then 0. That's pretty smart!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're registering the body.click handler repeatedly, and never removing it.  jQuery maintains a list of event listeners, so when you add the same click handler multiple times, it gets executed multiple times for each click.

I would set the body click handler once, in the document.ready event, and have it only hide the hour drop down if its currently visible, something like:

```
jQuery('.more').click(function() {
    if ($('.hour_dropdown').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.hour_dropdown').fadeToggle(200);
    }
});

jQuery('body').click(function() {
    if ($('.hour_dropdown').is(':visible')) {
        $('.hour_dropdown').fadeOut(200);
    }
 });
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a `ul` inside a `span` is invalid HTML. Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/PcWjA/25/

Answer (score 0):

Simply unbind the body click event and that will fix your problem.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hour_dropdown').hide()

    jQuery('.more').click(function() {
        if ($('.hour_dropdown').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.hour_dropdown').fadeToggle(200);
            $("body").unbind();

        } else {
            $('body').click(function() {
                $('.hour_dropdown').fadeOut(200);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that (hope this is the right behavior):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var element = $('.hour_dropdown');
    element.hide();

    $('body').click(function(event) {        
       if ( ('more' ==  $(event.target).attr('class') ) || (0 <  $(event.target).parents('.more').length ) ) {
          element.fadeIn(200);        
       } else {
          element.fadeOut(200);
       }
    });
});​
```

It checks whether the clicked element is exactly the one with class `more` or whether a parent has this class. It also stores the the element with the class `.hour_dropdown` in a variable and reduces requests and it has only one event handler.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6rXe/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually bind these types of events to the body, because it gets tough with event bubbling. I suggest making a fixed overlay that appears and handles the close event:

http://jsfiddle.net/PcWjA/33/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hour_dropdown').hide()

    $('.more').on('click', function() {
        $('.hour_dropdown').fadeToggle(200);
        $('#overlay').show();
    });

    $('#overlay').on('click', function() {
        $('.closeable').fadeOut();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the span like this : `<span id="more" class="more">`
And modify your JS code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hour_dropdown').hide()

    jQuery('.more').click(function() {
        if ($('.hour_dropdown').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.hour_dropdown').fadeToggle(200);
        } else {
            $('body').click(function(event) {
              if(event.target.id!="more")

                $('.hour_dropdown').fadeOut(200);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Your updated fiddle now looks like this : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PcWjA/34/)